# Boostache compilation error

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я собираюсь использовать [Boostache](https://github.com/cierelabs/boostache) но во время компиляции я получаю вот такое сообщение об ошибке:

[image: Boostache compilatin error]

В строке 72 [этого исходного кода](https://github.com/cierelabs/boostache/blob/master/include/boost/boostache/vm/traits.hpp)

```
template <typename T>
  using enable_if_sequence_not_map_t =
    typename std::enable_if<
        std::integral_constant< bool
                              , vm::trait::has_begin<T>::value
                                & !vm::trait::is_map<T>::value >::value
     >::type;
```

я получаю ошибку.
Я работаю в Visual Studio 14 2015 и с Boost 1.61.0. Какие правки мне нужно добавить чтобы избежать этой ошибки?

Comment: Заголовок некорректный. has_begin объявлена как тип функции, а к ней применяется оператор разрешения имени ::. Пишите жалобу разработчику этого заголовочного файла.:)

Comment: @Abyx Нде вы там увидели вызов функции? Это алиас объявления функции.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow По идее has_begin имеет тип std::integral_constant и оператор разрешения :: здесь уместен

Comment: @SpaceRabbit Это тип возвращаемого значения объявления функции, но сама функция нигде не вызвана, чтобы обращаться к к результату ее работы. И об этом говорит компилятор, то есть что объявление функции - это не объявление класса, а потому у нее нет членов данных.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Если я не ошибаюсь то возаращаемое значение has_begin_test и есть std::integral_constant

Comment: @SpaceRabbit Да, но это возвращаемый тип функции, но сама объявление имеет не этот тип, а тип функции, у которой нет членов данных и каких-то других внутренних объявлений типов.

Comment: @SpaceRabbit У вас в этом объявлении using mytype = decltype(myfunc());  в качестве выражения используется вызов функции, а не сам тип функции. Так как тип значением вызова функции является класс std::integral_constant, то конечно работает. Но в исходном заголовке  выражения с вызовом функции нет. Там используется сам тип  функции.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `template<class T>
   using has_begin = decltype(has_begin_test(std::declval<T>()));` здесь разве нет вызова функции has_begin_test?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49036/discussion-between-space-rabbit-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @SpaceRabbit У вас не компилируется авторский заголовок. Напишите об этом автору письмо. Пусть разбирается.

Answer (score 1):

Немогу дать внятного обьяснения но вот так все работает:

```
template <typename T>
using enable_if_sequence_not_map_t =
      typename std::enable_if<
         std::integral_constant< bool
                               , has_begin<T>::value
                                 & !is_map<T>::value >::value
      >::type;
```

Я заменил `vm::trait::has_begin<T>::value` на `has_begin<T>::value`
И `vm::trait::is_map<T>::value >::value` на `is_map<T>::value >::value`.
**Как это обьяснить?**

Повторил туже ошибку только с меньшим количеством кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace my_namespace
{
namespace my_namespace2
{
namespace my_namespace3
{
    typedef std::integral_constant<bool, true> my_t;

    template<class T>
    my_t myfunc(const T&);

    template<class T>
    using mytype = decltype(myfunc<T>(true));

    template<typename T>
    //using mytype2 = std::integral_constant<bool, mytype<T>::value>; // <-- работает
    using mytype2 = std::integral_constant<bool, my_namespace2::my_namespace3::mytype<T>::value>; // <-- не работает
}
}
}

void main()
{
    std::cout << "Do it !!!" << std::endl;
}
```